# Problem when I use @login_required in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

So I m in the route upload. I want that before upload a file log in. But the page of log in
appears and when I logged in flask redirect me to insert (because is define in login route, but if I delete the redirect flask return me Invalid username or password).

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('insert')) 
        return '<h1> Invalid username or password</h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    
    if request.method == "POST":

#I DON'T PUT THE ENTIRE CODE BECAUSE IT DOESN'T MAKE SENSE
```

After thath when I logged in (but in the route of log in) I want that flask redirect me to insert. So basically when I use login_required I wish to keep in the route that I put the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect back to upload after logging in, take advantage of the `next` parameter that the `@login_required` decorator adds. Using it looks something like

```
login_user(...)
next_page = request.args.get('next')
if next_page is not None and is_safe_url(next_page):
    return redirect(next_page)    # this'll get you back
else:
    return direct(...)  # some fallback page
```

But see the example in the Flask Login documentation [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) for full details.

Comment: Dude dont work me, keep the same error ('<h1> Invalid username or password</h1>'), is like the if is not fulfilled and pass to the else

Comment: I'm confused about what problem you're having. Could you clarify?

Comment: I put the decorator in /upload route, the problem is when I login (cause the login_required ask me and for there all is it ok) then redirect me to insert(I think because is in the code of log in route), when I need to redirect to the same page that I put the decorator . So I need a code like said something like that: login and than you will be enabled to keep in this page

Comment: I saw the documentation and I think the solution could be this: "USE_SESSION_FOR_NEXT is True" but I don t understand how to use it